# Change value on src img tag before scraper data?

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

Hi evry one i have this code:

```
foreach ($image as $snimka){
    $url = $snimka->src;
    $ch = curl_init($snimka->src);
    $fp = fopen('images/' . basename($url), 'wb');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
    echo basename($url);
    echo '<br />';
}
```

This code working perfect but before starting to draw pictures to shift part of the src and that is what I have in mind the following src 
partnersite.com/363-cart_default/kecove-nora-zhylto-i-sinio.jpg I want to change just one word from the cart to become large and only then start to download the picture how to do please help

I resolved my problem this is solution :

```
 foreach ($image as $snimka){
        $url = $snimka->src;
        $replace = preg_replace('~cart~','large',$url);
        $ch = curl_init($replace);
        $fp = fopen('images/' . basename($url), 'wb');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        fclose($fp);
        echo basename($url);
        echo '<br />';
  }
```

Comment: not my web site i curl download image on my partner site.Hi is not xml file and i create scraper

Comment: Sorry. I misread it for a second there.

Comment: If you want to change something in a string to something else, try [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Comment: The question isn't specific enough. Please post a clear sample of input/output . i.e.: "__i have this__" and  "__I need this__".

Answer (score 0):

Base on your current question here is an example how _default/ can change into _large/.

```
echo preg_replace ( '|_default\/|', '_large/' , 'partnersite.com/363-cart_default/kecove-nora-zhylto-i-sinio.jpg');
```